# How to start JUnit tests separately?

Tags: java, junit

I am  new in JUnit and I found a lot of examples in web, but all of them show me a class of tests, where they start in sequence. I have the follow test class:

```
public class ControlServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {

        //some stuff

    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginUser() {

        //some stuff

    }
}
```

But i need to start only one test at same time, not both. I will be glad if somebody explain me how can I do it.

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: no, actually I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse:

Right click on the specific test that you want to run in Outline, Run As -> JUnit Test.

Comment: so simple... Thank you! I am using Android Studio, but it works there too.

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin In Android Studio/IntelliJ, put your cursor inside a test method and hot Ctrl-Shift-F10 (Windows) or Ctrl-shift-R (Mac), and it will run that method only. If you put the cursor in the test class, but outside of a test method, the same shortcut will run all the tests in the class.